# Can I get the Swagger interface to appear on a deployed Azure web API?

Tags: azure-devops, swagger, azure-pipelines, openapi, azure-devops-rest-api

When one creates an ASP.NET Core Web API in Visual Studio 2022, and tests it locally, one gets a convenient Swagger page built upon an OpenAPI definition, to test all HTTP endpoints.

However, when deployed and trying to access `{path-to-api}/swagger`, it returns a `404 Not Found` error, even while on `localhost`, when both the API and the database is sitting on my own machine. Even if the database is in the Azure cloud, for that matter, it also works, if I put the Azure SQL Database connection string into appsettings.json.

So is there a way to achieve this, preferably without too much hassle? Or am I wrong in wanting this, do developers mostly test their APIs locally? Because I want the Swagger API online only for testing.

---

The problem is getting and using the swagger functionality into the cloud. Is it possible and good practice?

Comment: Can you try to call the exact API from the URL? I guess this works. For example call `https://YOURSITE-webappstatic.azurewebsites.net/weatherforecast`

Comment: I removed the Weatherforecast altogether, but an endpoint which I have, /api/Course, works.

Comment: I checked your question and the answers . it's a good way to follow their steps to try it first. If the solution is indeed helpful, you could mark it as a correct answer to let other one know the solutions. If you have any questions and need help, we are happy to help you.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the startup, you will notice that the swagger is only loaded during a development session via an `if` check. Commenting that out, or expanding it based on evironment, will allow a published version to generate the page on the target host.

```
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
```

---

I generally do that for first publishes or to Dev/Test environments to see it running. Once it is not needed, I un-comment it back in.

Also it may be actually viable (turned on) in Dev or UAT server because one is *also* publishing *the open api* it to APIM (Azure api manager), which takes the api and generates its own development environment; away from an initial publish.

---

Also once published, it is not the *default* page, one still has to path to it such as `.../swagger/index.html`.

Comment: how do you "path" to it?

Comment: `http://{BaseUrl}/swagger/index.html`

Answer (score 0):

I'm aborting this mission to deploy the Swagger interface to Azure along with my API. It's bad security practice to make the HTTP request methods so visually available to all. So the answer to my question *do developers mostly test their APIs locally,* is apparently yes.

I wondered if I should remove the question, but I would like to make it still stand, in case anyone else is contemplating about doing the same thing - exposing an API online with the Swagger UI.